# How To Delete Multiple Items from ListView C# With Delete Button

Tags: c#, listview, multi-select, multiline, delete-row

So, I have a simple ListView that users can add information to and a delete button that is only capable of deleting one selected item at a time. I'm trying to make it so that when multiple items are selected and 'delete' is pressed it deletes those selected items instead of just one. Your help is appreciated!

**Add recipient code:**

```
 private void addtoRecipients_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (recipientEmailBox.Text != "")
        {
            string[] S = new string[4];
            S[0] = recipientEmailBox.Text;
            S[1] = recipientNameBox.Text;
            S[2] = txtLocation.Text;
            S[3] = txtSubject.Text;
            ListViewItem I = new ListViewItem(S);
            recipientBox.Items.Add(I);
            UpdateNoOfEmails();
        }
    }
```

**My Delete Button Code (only deletes one selection at the moment)**

```
 private void deleteEntryBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try { recipientBox.Items.Remove(recipientBox.SelectedItems[0]); }

        catch { }
        UpdateNoOfEmails();
    }
```

**Clear All Recipients Code**

```
private void clearBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recipientBox.Items.Clear();
        UpdateNoOfEmails();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the simplest way to do it was with a while loop. This is what my new delete button code looks like:

```
 private void deleteEntryBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            while (recipientBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                recipientBox.Items.Remove(recipientBox.SelectedItems[0]);
            }
        }

        catch { }
        UpdateNoOfEmails();
    }
```